# are multiple linear white space allowed in http header

Tags: http, http-headers, web-standards

I'm trying to understand http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2

> HTTP/1.1 header field values can be folded onto multiple lines if the
>   continuation line begins with a space or horizontal tab. All linear
>   white space, including folding, has the same semantics as SP. A
>   recipient MAY replace any linear white space with a single SP before
>   interpreting the field value or forwarding the message downstream.
>
> ```
>    LWS            = [CRLF] 1*( SP | HT )
> ```

Can i put any number of `<CR><LF><SP>`, without putting any header value on the line ?
i.e. is this valid : `Header:<CR><LF><SP><CR><LF><SP>Value`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31237198/632951

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-22.html#rfc.section.3.2.4.p.3 - it's deprecated in the upcoming revision of the HTTP spec.

Comment: hmmm so world is not using fgets() any more (-: